# Second thread hangs when starting Wi-Fi

Tags: multithreading, wifi, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

I want to serve an HTML page from a Raspberry Pi Pico W to monitor and control it from a browser. If I un-comment last line and run it in Thonny (not as a thread) it works and I can turn on and off the LED on the Raspberry Pi Pico W from my browser, so it's something about how code runs in a thread:

```
# Test Web server based on an example found here
# https://how2electronics.com/raspberry-pi-pico-w-web-server-tutorial-with-micropython/

import machine
import socket
#import math
import network
import time
import secretsHouse

# Temperature Sensor
sensor_temp = machine.ADC(4)
conversion_factor = 3.3 / (65535)

# Pin Definitions
ledPin = 5                                   # Physical Pin 7  Gnd = 8
led = machine.Pin(ledPin, machine.Pin.OUT)   # Define pin as output


def webServerMain():
    print("*Thread2*    Main()")
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    print("*Thread2*    wlan="+str(wlan))
    try:
        print("*Thread2*    try wlan.active(True)")
        wlan.active(True)
        print("*Thread2*    wlan=active")
    except Exception as errorMsg:
        print("*Thread2*    Error="+str(errorMsg))

    wlan.connect(secretsHouse.ssid,secretsHouse.password)

    # Wait for connect or fail
    print("*Thread2*   WIFI Connect Wait=10")
    wait = 10
    while wait > 0:
        if wlan.status() < 0 or wlan.status() >= 3:
            break
        wait -= 1
        print('*Thread2*    waiting for wifi connection...'+str(wait))
        time.sleep(2)

    # Handle connection error
    if wlan.status() != 3:
        print("*Thread2*    "+str(wlan.status()))
        raise RuntimeError('*Thread2    *wifi connection failed')
    else:
        print('*Thread2*    Wifi Connected')
        ip=wlan.ifconfig()[0]
        print('*Thread2*    IP: ', ip)

    try:
        if ip is not None:
            connection=open_socket(ip)
            serve(connection)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        machine.reset()

def temperature():
    temperature_value = sensor_temp.read_u16() * conversion_factor
    temperature_Celcius = 27 - (temperature_value - 0.706)/0.00172169/ 8
    print("*Thread2*  Temp=" + str(temperature_Celcius))
    time.sleep(2)
    return temperature_Celcius

def webpage(value):
    html = f"""
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <body>
            <form action="./led">
            <input type="submit" value="Led On" />
            </form>
            <form action="./off">
            <input type="submit" value="Led Off" />
            </form>
            <p>Temperature is {value} degrees Celsius</p>
            </body>
            </html>
            """
    return html

def serve(connection):
    while True:
        print("*Thread2*    serve() While Loop.... (Wait for web request)")
        client = connection.accept()[0]
        print("*Thread2*    serve() client=" + str(client))
        print()
        request = client.recv(1024)
        print("*Thread2*    request="+str(request))
        request = str(request)
        print()
        try:
            request = request.split()[1]
        except IndexError:
            print("IndexError")
            pass
        print()
        print("*Thread2*    Request=" + str(request))

        if request == '/off?':
            led.low()
        elif request == '/led?':
            led.high()

        value='%.2f'%temperature()
        html=webpage(value)
        client.send(html)
        client.close()

def open_socket(ip):
    # Open a socket
    print("*Thread2*    open_socket()")
    address = (ip, 80)
    connection = socket.socket()
    connection.bind(address)
    connection.listen(1)
    print("*Thread2*    connection="+str(connection))
    return(connection)

#webServerMain()  # Enable this line to run not in a thread
```

If I comment out last line and run the code in a separate thread, the foreground thread runs but the background thread stops with this output:

```
*Thread2*    Main()
*Thread1*    Count=1
*Thread2*    wlan=<CYW43 STA down 0.0.0.0>
*Thread2*    try wlan.active(True)
*Thread1*    Count=2
*Thread1*    Count=3
*Thread1*    Count=4
*Thread1*    Count=5
*Thread1*    Count=6
*Thread1*    Count=7
*Thread1*    Count=8
*Thread1*    Count=9
*Thread1*    Count=10
*Thread1*    Count=11
*Thread1*    Count=12
*Thread1*    Count=13
*Thread1*    Count=14
*Thread1*    Count=15
```

Code that executes the thread:

```
# Test Thread
import _thread
import time
import webServerExample
import testTone

_thread.start_new_thread(webServerExample.webServerMain,())
#_thread.start_new_thread(testTone.beep,())

count=0
while True:
    count=count+1
    print("*Thread1*    Count="+str(count))
    time.sleep(2)
```

What am I doing wrong? I think it's the Wi-Fi starting that stops second thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a work around than an answer.

If I put the WIFI stuff in the main thread and then start a second thread that does something trivial it works no problem.  I'll rebuild my actual application to function this way and see if something else kills the sub thread.

I'm not sure if this behavior is a bug in Micropython threading?

I'll create a new question with a bare bones example that demonstrates the problem with just the WIFI connection and not much more than a counter or two.
David